# How to fix div height in container

Tags: html, css

I made a login screen but I am facing an issue.
I made one container and i divided it into two divs inside the container. The divs are (col-md-7 & col-md-5) the issue is right side div(col-md-5) I added color but div height is not filling the entire area [Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGVT9.png)

Here is the Code:

```css
.bg-form {
    background: #1d2b36;
    padding: 50px;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 84vh;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please share your markup too so that we can help you

Comment: Are you working with bootstrap? It could help, if you would add it as a tag.